# Cassandra change replication factor hive datastore

Tags: replication, cassandra

I am trying to change replication factor of HiveMetaStore but I receive this message:

```
cassandra@cqlsh:system> alter KEYSPACE HiveMetaStore with replication = 
    {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DCassandra1': 1};
```

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown keyspace hivemetastore"

HiveMetaStore keyspace exists. What could be the problem?

I changed replication factor from OpsCenter and it worked.

Why was I not able to change id from cqlsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default cql will convert the table/keyspace/column name in lowercase.
If you have table/keyspace/column in uppercase you have to enclose it in double quotes.

```
alter KEYSPACE "HiveMetaStore" with replication = 
    {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DCassandra1': 1};
```

Opscenter handled it for you:)

[CQL UpperCase/lowercase](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html)